# Health Cloud - Storing Fitness Data

Tags: health-cloud

New to salesforce health-cloud!

I am planning to store fitness-related data such as weight, steps count, blood glucose, and other health-related information. After some research, I found that there are standard objects in health-cloud like caremetrics and activity objects, but I'm not sure what the best architecture for this type of data storage would be.

Can someone suggest which standard objects I should use and provide some insights on the architecture I should adopt for storing this type of data? Is there any specific design pattern or architecture that is recommended for such use-cases? I want to make sure that the data is easily accessible and that it can be used for generating meaningful insights.

Thanks in advance!